# Showing the a function $f(A,B)=A \cup B$ is a surjection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am stuck on how to show the following:

$\;$

Let S and T be sets. Define a function

$$f:\mathscr{P}(S)\times\mathscr{P}(T) \mapsto\mathscr{P}(S \cup T) $$

by $\;f(A,B)=A \cup B$ for all $A \subseteq S$ and all $B \subseteq T$. Show that $f$ is a surjection.

$\;$

I understand that the function must map to every element of $\mathscr{P}(S \cup T) $. I honestly have no idea of how to even start showing this though. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C$ be a subset of $S\cup T$

Define $A=C\cap S$ and $B=C\cap T$

Then you have $f(A,B) = C$

Thus $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I understand this for the function mapping to every element of $S \cup T$, but I am confused how this shows that the function maps to every element of the power set of $S \cup T$?

Comment: Each  element of the power set of  $S\cup T$ is a subset of  $S\cup T$ and $C$ is an arbitrary subset of $S\cup T$, so every subset is covered.

Comment: That clears it up then, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Let $D\subseteq S\cup T$.

Now find sets $A\subseteq S$  and $B\subseteq T$ such that $D=A\cup B$.

Then $f(A,B)=D$ and this can be done for *every* $D\subseteq S\cup T$ (surjectivity).